# 'use' directive while using ReflectionClass in symfony app

Tags: php, symfony

I have a class in my symfony 3 app with a method that should instantiate a Model class dynamically using the name that's passed in to the function, i.e.:

```
static function getInstance($modelName){

    use $modelName;

    $r = new \ReflectionClass($modelName);
    return $r->newInstanceArgs();
}
```

But there's a syntax error on the `use` directive.

I've tried adding specific `use` statements for every class at the top of the file; and I've also tried using `require` with a fully qualified path to the corresponding PHP file - but neither approach has worked.

Please advise how to correctly do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this? use qualified class name

```
static function getInstance($modelName){
    $r = new \ReflectionClass('AppBundle\Entity\\' . $modelName);
    return $r->newInstanceArgs();
}
```

Comment: I just realised this after I posted the question

Comment: There is no need to escape \ after Entity.. `$r = new \ReflectionClass('AppBundle\Entity\' . $modelName);` would work too..

Answer (score 0):

Also, per [PHP USE Documentation:](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

> ### Scoping rules for importing
>
> The use keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because the importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be block scoped. The following example will show an illegal use of the use keyword:
>
> #### Example #5 Illegal importing rule

```
namespace Languages;

function toGreenlandic() {
    use Languages\Danish;
}
```